# activate exchange PowerShell commands

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have to use commands like:

```
Get-TransportServer
Get-OrganizationConfig
Get-MessageTrackingLog
```

But it seems I have to do something on my Exchange server before I can use them?
I get an `ObjectNotFound` error message.

Thanks for your help.

Here are the code and the error:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-OrganizationConfig | Select ReadTrackingEnabled

Get-OrganizationConfig : The term 'Get-OrganizationConfig' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-OrganizationConfig | Select ReadTrackingEnabled
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-OrganizationConfig:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your question to show the code you have written and the full error message ?

Comment: OK but. It will sadly be in french...

Comment: I'm french : ) I'll translate if needed : )

Comment: Are you using the classic PowerShell console or the Exchange Management Shell ? This last one has the Exchange cmdlets you need. I think you can load them in a classic console but it seems not to be recommended. I'll run a few tests and make an answer :).

Comment: Sorry I even didn't know an Exchange Management Console existed. There is no "talk" about it in all tutorials I'm reading. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most certainly running these commands outside the Exchange Management Shell. It's a PowerShell console using a specific console file and loading additional cmdlets, i.e. the ones you need here.

See this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505910.aspx

Related question about loading the cmdlets in a classic PowerShell console : [Exchange Powershell - How to invoke Exchange 2010 module from inside script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035902/exchange-powershell-how-to-invoke-exchange-2010-module-from-inside-script)