# Run Exchange command from Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, ems

I've connected to EMS from Windows Powershell using the below:

`&"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1 "`

I can't run `Get-ExCommands` or `Disable-Mailbox -Identity Test` without getting an error. "The term Get-ExCommands is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script..."

Is it possible to run Exchange commands in Win Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
. 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto
```

If you did not install the Exchange Management Tools on the server you are using you can connect to exchange this way:

```
$s = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri http://putyourservernamehere/Powershell  -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange 
import-pssession $s
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to import the Exchange PowerShell module. Take a look at this:
[Exchange Powershell - How to invoke Exchange 2010 module from inside script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035902/exchange-powershell-how-to-invoke-exchange-2010-module-from-inside-script)